# Dynamic Queries pass to sql function

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio

How can I pass dynamic queries to following function as I want each time data in my main program by providing dynamic case queries.

Public Class DBConnection

```
Function MyDBConnection(ByRef sqlquery As String)


    Dim sCommand As SqlCommand
    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
    Dim sDs As DataSet
    Dim connectionString As String = "Data Source=ATIFTARIQ;Initial Catalog=ABC_University;Integrated Security=True"

    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    sCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlquery, connection)
    sAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sCommand)
    sBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(sAdapter)
    sDs = New DataSet()
    sAdapter.Fill(sDs, "Files")
    connection.Close()
    Return sDs

End Function
```

Comment: What is your question? This has the look of a very bad solution to me. It is generally a bad idea to pass your queries to a generic function like this. It is an indication that you are probably not using parameterized queries and instead building up strings and executing them which is vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: it will be useful for me to change table and query type as per user need.

Comment: Well again, this design is a very bad approach as it exposes your system to sql injection. But regardless you still haven't actually asked a question. What are you trying to do and what do you need help with.